# Remove pins when clustering google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am having an issue with google map clustering pins. The problem is that after clustering is done the pins don't dissapear.

array here

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var marker_new = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map
                  });
new_markers.push(marker_new);
```

after array is done

```
clusterStyles = [
        {
        textColor: '#ffffff',    
        opt_textColor: '#ffffff',
        url: mapfunctions_vars.path+'/cloud.png',
        height: 72,
        width: 72,
        textSize:15,

        }
    ];
    mcOptions = {
        gridSize: 100,
        ignoreHidden:true, 
        maxZoom: mapfunctions_vars.zoom_cluster, 
        styles: clusterStyles
    };
    var mcsluster;

    mcsluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, new_markers, mcOptions);
    mcsluster.setIgnoreHidden(true);
```

Any ideas how i can remove them ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question itself** (not a link to a broken site) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add your markers to the map, merely create them with coordinates.  Just change:

```
var marker_new = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
});
```

to:

```
var marker_new = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng
});
```

You can see this in the example in the documentation:
https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
        dataPhoto.longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) that wasted 2 days of my life

Answer (score 0):

One thing we do on our project is looping through the markers every time we need to update them and clear them using the code below.

```html
                    for (var i = 0; i < new_markers.length; i++) {
                        // cleanup event listener reference
                        google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(new_markers[i]);
                        // cleanup marker instance
                        new_markers[i].setMap(null);
                    }
```

Also, there is a clearMarkers() method on the MarketClusterer object that we use. I hope this helps a bit.